# How to dispose/close/release iText 7's control of newly created pdfs

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I can create multiple pdf documents using iText 7. However, after creation I want to send an email with the newly created pdfs as attachments. This results in sharing violation error. See my steps below.

First I have a static class to initialize pdfs called PDFLibrary:

```
public static PdfWriter CreateWriter(string Filepath)
{
    //set writer properties
    WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
    writerProperties.SetStandardEncryption(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(""), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("password"), EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING, EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(Filepath, writerProperties);
    //set compression level
    writer.SetCompressionLevel(9);  //0 = best speed, 9 = best compression, -1 is default
    return writer;
}

public static PdfDocument CreatePDFDocument(PdfWriter Writer)
{
    return new PdfDocument(Writer);
}

public static Document CreateDocument(PdfDocument PDFDoc)
{
    Document document = new Document(PDFDoc);
    document.SetMargins(25,25,25,25);
    return document;
}
```

Then I reference the above class and methods:

```
PdfWriter writer;
PdfDocument pdfDocument;
Document doc;

private void CreatePDFs(string PDFPath)
{
    writer = PDFLibrary.CreateWriter(PDFPath);
    pdfDocument = PDFLibrary.CreatePDFDocument(writer);
    doc = PDFLibrary.CreateDocument(pdfDocument);
}
```

Finally (after adding tables and cells to create the desired pdfs), I close the pdf objects:

```
private void CloseDocumentStreams()
{
    doc.Close();
    writer.SetCloseStream(true);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Now attempting the following operation in a send email method results in an "IOException: Sharing violation on path":

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(pathToPDF[i]);
```

Is there a way to fully release iText's handle over the documents? The [example documentation](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-chapter-1) only shows `document.Close()` where `document` is type `Document`.

Comment: It's hard to tell without your code. You haven't called `SetCloseStream(false)`, have you?

Comment: @mkl See my updated question and let me know if that helps clarify the situation

Comment: Just for testing sake, simplify things and use `using` statements, then build backup from there.

Comment: It *looks* sufficient. Actually, closing the `doc` or the `pdfDocument` should suffice. At least as long as no error occurs, of course. Usually, therefore,  working with `using` is better. I assume you don't open a viewing component for the pdf in the time between, so you?

Comment: I figured it out. The error specifically mentioned there was a sharing violation on the first pdf I created which made me realize I only called the CloseDocumentStreams() on the last loop of the create pdfs function. I was trying to avoid posting the entirety of the code (3,000+ lines) but I should've included more than I did. Thank you everyone for your help!